# Trouble adding click event to ListView

Tags: wpf, events, listview, click, double-click

My problem is that I already have a GridViewColumnHeader.Click event for the ListView ( to sort columns) but I need an additional click event for when a user clicks on an element in the row.

The reason this gets difficult is that I also already have a DoubleClick event for the items. So my initial idea to add MouseUp or Down events, stops my DoubleClick code from working.

Any help is greatly appreciated, also working in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [MouseButtonEventArgs.ClickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs.clickcount.aspx) in your MouseDown handler and verify that it's 1. If it's not 1, then you'd ignore it and don't set e.Handled to true. This would allow the double click event to still be raised.